# SQLite Primary Key search in multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, primary-key

I have an SQLite3 database that contains several tables.

All of these tables include a unique INTEGER column named cID set to Primary Key.

There will be an undetermined number of these tables.

Is there a way to (as speedily as possible) search over all of these tables for one record based on a Primary Key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your tables, doing:

`SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE cID = [the cID you're interested in]`.

FYI, the primary key only needs to be unique across records in a single table - it does not need to be unique across all tables.